# Big-O analysis of two algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I created two solutions for [leetcode problem 17](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/) in which it asks you to generate all possible text strings from a phone number combination, e.g. `"3"` results in `["d","e","f"]`.

My first solution uses a recursive algorithm to generate the strings and is given below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void fill_LUT(vector<string>& lut) {
        lut.clear();
        lut.push_back(" ");
        lut.push_back("");
        lut.push_back("abc");
        lut.push_back("def");
        lut.push_back("ghi");
        lut.push_back("jkl");
        lut.push_back("mno");
        lut.push_back("pqrs");
        lut.push_back("tuv");
        lut.push_back("wxyz");
    }

    void generate_strings(int index, string& digits, vector<string>& lut, vector<string>& r, string& work) {
        if(index >= digits.size()) {
            r.push_back(work);
            return;
        }

        char idx = digits[index] - '0';
        for(char c : lut[idx]) {
            work.push_back(c);
            generate_strings(index+1, digits, lut, r, work);
            work.pop_back();
        }
    }

    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        vector<string> r;
        vector<string> lut;
        fill_LUT(lut);

        if(digits.size() <= 0)
            return r;

        string work;
        generate_strings(0, digits, lut, r, work);

        return r;
    }
};
```

I am a bit rusty with big-O, but it appears to me that the space complexity would be `O(n)` for the recursive call, i.e. its maximum depth, `O(n)` for the buffer string, and `O(n*c^n)` for the resulting strings. Would this sum together as `O(n+n*c^n)`?

For time complexity I am a bit confused. Each level of the recursion performs `c` pushes + pops + recursive calls multiplied by the number of operations by the next level, so it sounds like `c^1 + c^2 + ... + c^n`. In addition, there are `c^n` duplications of `n` length strings. **How do I consolidate this into a nice big-O representation?**

---

The second solution views the number of results as a mixed radix number and converts it to a string as you might perform an int to hex string conversion:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void fill_LUT(vector<string>& lut) {
        lut.clear();
        lut.push_back(" ");
        lut.push_back("");
        lut.push_back("abc");
        lut.push_back("def");
        lut.push_back("ghi");
        lut.push_back("jkl");
        lut.push_back("mno");
        lut.push_back("pqrs");
        lut.push_back("tuv");
        lut.push_back("wxyz");
    }

    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        vector<string> r;
        vector<string> lut;
        fill_LUT(lut);

        if(digits.size() <= 0)
            return r;

        unsigned total = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++) {
            digits[i] = digits[i]-'0';
            auto m = lut[digits[i]].size();
            if(m > 0) total *= m;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int current = i;
            r.push_back(string());
            string& s = r.back();
            for(char c : digits) {
                int radix = lut[c].size();
                if(radix != 0) {
                    s.push_back(lut[c][current % radix]);
                    current = current / radix;
                }
            }
        }

        return r;
    }
};
```

In this case, I believe that the space complexity is `O(n*c^n)` similar to the first solution minus the buffer and recursion, and the time complexity must be `O(n)` for the first for loop and an additional `O(n*c^n)` to create a result string for each of the possible results. The final big-O for this is `O(n+n*c^n)`. **Is my thought process correct?**

---

**Edit:** To add some clarification to the code, imagine an input string of `"234"`. The first recursive solution will call `generate_strings` with the arguments `(0, "234", lut, r, work)`. `lut` is a look up table that converts a number to its corresponding characters. `r` is the vector containing the resulting strings. `work` is a buffer where the work is performed.

The first recursive call will then see that the index `0` digit is `2` which corresponds with `"abc"`, push `a` to `work`, and then call `generate_strings` with the arguments `(1, "234", lut, r, work)`. Once the call returns it will then push `b` to `work` and rinse and repeat.

When `index` is equal to the size of `digits` then a unique string has been generated and the string is pushed onto `r`.

---

For the second solution, the input string is first converted from it's ascii representation to it's integer representation. For example `"234"` is converted to `"\x02\x03\x04"`. Then the code uses those as indices to look up the number of corresponding characters in the lookup table and calculates the total number of strings that will be in the result. e.g. if the input string was `"234"`, `2` corresponds with `abc`, which has 3 characters. `3` corresponds with `def` which has 3 characters. `4` corresponds with `ghi` which has 3 characters. The total number of possible strings is `3*3*3 = 27`.

Then the code uses a counter to represent each of the possible strings. If `i` were `15` it would be evaluated by first finding `15 % 3` which is `0`, corresponding with the first character for the first digit (`a`). Then divide `15` by `3` which is `5`. `5 % 3` is `2` which corresponds with the third character for the second digit, which is `f`. Finally divide `5` by `3` and you get `1`. `1 % 3` is `1` which corresponds with the second character for the third digit, `h`. Therefore the string that corresponds with the number `15` is `afh`. This is performed for each number and the resulting strings are stored in `r`.

Comment: Can you explain the algo ideas in English ? It save alot of headache when reading the code.

Comment: When you have O, c^n dominates n. You can simply say it's O(c^n) and be correct.

Comment: @cuongptnk sure, I added some more detail at the end of my question.

Comment: What is `c` in your calculations?

Comment: @n.m. It is just a constant. In this case it would be 4 since 7 and 9 correspond with 4 characters on the phone.

Comment: @PaulStelian Thanks. With big-O would you always drop the dominated terms? For example with `O(n+n^2)` would you simplify it to `O(n^2)`?

Comment: I check. Your analysis is almost perfect. Except the O(n*c^n) is O(c^n). I do not see why we need to multiply by n.

Comment: @Alden: Yup. Big-O sort of imagines the terms going to infinity, so even `O(10000n + n^1.01)` would technically simplify to `O(n ^ 1.01)`, because for large `n`, the linear growth is dwarfed. Admittedly, in a case like this, the official big-O would probably be supplemented with a note about the large linear factor.

Comment: Unless phone numbers become quite large - which would present a significant usability problem for all sorts of reasons since humans have trouble remembering them or typing them in - it will be performance (speed, memory usage) for representative phone numbers that matters, not big-O complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recursive algorithm:**

Space: each level of recursion is O(1) and there are O(n) levels. Thus it is O(n) for the recursion. The space of result is O(c^n), where c = max(lut[i].length). Total space for the algorithm is O(c^n).

Time: Let T(n) be the cost for digit with length n. Then we have recursion formula : T(n) <= c T(n-1) + O(1). Solve this equation give T(n) = O(c^n).

**Hashing algorithm:**

Space: if you need the space to store all results, then it is still O(c^n).

Time: O(n+c^n) = O(c^n).

---

I like the **Hashing algorithm** because it is better if the question asks you to give a specific string result (suppose we order them by alphabet order). In that case, the space and time is only O(n).

This question reminds me to a similar question: generate all permutations of the set {1,2,3,...,n}. The hashing approach is better because by generating the permutation one by one and process it, we can save a lot of space.